# if and only if there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^{2016} + x^{2015} + \cdots + 1 \equiv p^{2016} \pmod{p^{2017}}$.

Tags: number-theory

> Find the set $S$ of primes such that $p \in S$ if and only if there exists an integer $x$ such that $$x^{2016} + x^{2015} + \cdots + 1 \equiv p^{2016} \pmod{p^{2017}}$$.

My attemp:
First, note that if $x$ satisfies the problem condition, then we in particular have $\Phi_{2017}(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ which implies $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2017}$.

other hand I can't prove it,Thanks

Comment: The keyword to the converse statement is Hensel's lemma. Also you need to check the case $p=2017$.

Comment: How to use Hensel's lemma

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be: $S = \{p \quad | \quad p \equiv 1 \pmod{2017}\}$.

The first step is to find all $p$ such that $x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ admits a solution. There are two situations:

1. $x = 1$ is a solution. This happens only when $p = 2017$.
2. $x = 1$ is not a solution. Then you can equivalently look for $x$ such that $x^{2017} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Since $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, if $2017\not | (p-1)$ you will get $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ which is a contradiction. In this case we need $2017 | (p-1)$ (and you actually get 2016 distinct solutions for $x$ in this case. why?).

Suppose we are now getting a solution $x_0$ in the sense that $x_0^{2016} + \cdots + x_0 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$. We then need to extend from $x_0$ to the $\pmod{p^{2017}}$ situation. Again let us look at what we have in the two cases:

1. $2017 | (p-1)$: Suppose $x_0^{2016} + \cdots + x_0 + 1 \equiv cp \pmod {p^2}$, and suppose that $x_1 = x_0 + ap$. Then we aim to solve $x_1^{2016} + \cdots + x_1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$. By expansion,

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1^{2016} + \cdots + x_1 + 1 &\equiv x_0^{2016} + \cdots + 1 + 2016apx_0^{2015} + 2015apx^{2014} + \cdots + 2apx_0 + ap\\
&\equiv cp + ap\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1)\Big|_{x = x_0} \quad \pmod{p^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

The key fact is that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1)\Big|_{x = x_0} \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$, so you can solve for $a$. This is true because we remarked before that there are 2016 distinct values $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{2016}$ modulo $p$ such that $p | (\alpha_i^{2016} + \cdots + \alpha_i + 1)$ for $i = 1, \cdots, 2016$. This actually implies

$$
x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1 \equiv (x-\alpha_1)\cdots (x-\alpha_{2016}) \pmod p,
$$
and also implies $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1)\Big|_{x = x_0} \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Alright, now we get through the first step, and the rest are pretty much the same: as $x_1^{2016} + \cdots + x_1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$, by putting $x_2 = x_1 + ap^2$ you should find some $x_2$ satisfying $x_2^{2016} + \cdots + x_2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^4}$; then take $x_3 = x_2 + ap^4$ gives you some $x_3$ such that $x_3^{2016} + \cdots + x_3 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^8}$, and you take iterations. (Note that you need some extra care when you get close to $p^{2016}$).

2. $p=2017$: Of course we want to play the same game. Since we took $x_0 = 1$, $x_0^{2016} + \cdots + x_0 + 1 \equiv 2017 \pmod {2017^2}$, and suppose that $x_1 = x_0 + ap$. The tragedy is that regardless of $a$ you get $x_1^{2016} + \cdots + x_1 + 1 \equiv 2017 \pmod {2017^2}$. Oops.

   The reason that we fail in this case is because now $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2016} + \cdots + x + 1)\Big|_{x = x_0} \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

---

With some knowledge of the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ there is a more concise way to prove this, using Hensel's lemma applied on the function $f(x) = x^{2016} + \cdots + x + (1-p^{2016})$. If you look at the proof of Hensel's lemma, what we have done is actually the main ingredient of its proof.